# scss hide select arrow, appearance & -webkit-appearance: none; not working

Tags: css, sass

I need to hide the dropdown arrows on my select boxes when they are disable. From every thing I have read, this should work?

```
select.btn-underline-primary {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding-left: 0;
    color: $dark !important;
    option {
        border: none;
    }
    &:disabled {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        &::-ms-expand {
            display: none;
        }
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that applying `display: none` to the **[`::ms-expand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-expand)** only hides the dropdown for Internet Explorer 10 and 11. If you additionally want to hide it for Firefox / Chrome , you'll need to apply **[`-moz-appearance: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)** and **[`-webkit-appearance: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)** to the `select` respectively.

Note that `:disabled` is an attribute of the `select` element itself, and does not create a separate pseudo-class in the DOM. As such, you'll need a separate selector:

```
select.btn-underline-primary:disabled
```

Which combined with the rest of the code looks like:

```
select.btn-underline-primary {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: $dark !important;
  option {
    border: none;
  }
  &::-ms-expand {
    display: none; /* Hide dropdown in IE 10 & 11 */
  }
}

select.btn-underline-primary:disabled {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Hide dropdown in Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hide dropdown in Chrome */
}
```

This can be seen working on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01d2be23/)**.

Comment: yea if you look closely, this is pretty much the same as I was doing. I tested your code however and it's not working. I am starting to think this is having something to do with the Angular attribute binding in the HTML template.